# Mongodb dynamic column count

Tags: mongodb, database-design

Hi i am making a straw poll website. I am using `node.js` for server and `mongodb` for database. My database structure is like this

`objectId | userId | createdDate | endDate | dynamic columns`

`dynamic columns` is for example one record has 3 choice, another record has 6 choice. Database with dynamic columns is should look like this.

`randomId | admin | 07.03.2017 | 10.03.2017 | ch1-47 | ch2-20 | ch3-200`

`randomId | user2 | 07.03.2017 | 15.03.2017 | ch1-21 | ch2-7`

and so. `chN` means Nth choice. And number that comes after `chN` is how much times it rated. When someone rates choice 1 in first poll, the database should look like this.

`randomId | admin | 07.03.2017 | 10.03.2017 | ch1-48 | ch2-20 | ch3-200`

`randomId | user2 | 07.03.2017 | 15.03.2017 | ch1-21 | ch2-7`

Is mongodb have dynamic columns, if it have how can i make something like this?

Comment: As long as you are having a valid JSON, MongoDB will accept anything. Moreover, in MongoDB there is nothing as columns. Just JSON objects. You may want to read about document(row in SQL database) structure first. This link will help you https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/

Comment: @RaR That is perfect. Thanks for your comment :)